# Java/ Open a website with a proxy and stream a radio

Tags: java, proxy, stream

I want that i keep the radio open(http://sekundensparer.de/radio/start.php)
I dont want to hear the radio. I only want to download the stream.
To get the Users.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("104.131.118.88", 3128));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
          connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0");
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


             StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
             String inputLine;
             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
               response.append(inputLine);
             }


             System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: What's your problem,or what be happended about above code?

Comment: It connects to the Site. But it doesnt download the radio stream.

Comment: I think the Proxy is not valid,so you can run your code without proxy,and see the result.

Comment: same. The proxy works fine.

Comment: The output: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7200; URL=http://sekundensparer.de/radio/start.php?uid=618"><script language="JavaScript" src="http://sekundensparer.de/radio/rdsrcv2.php?uid=618"></script>

Comment: Your code just download the html stream of the url,if you want download the radio stream,you should analysis the javascript of the url.The radio stream is not be transfer by html,so you should monitor the data flow when browser open the url and radio.